# Easy proof that compact implies bounded in a metric space… too easy?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, metric-spaces, solution-verification, compactness

I came up with a proof that I have not seen anywhere and I’m wondering if it is because it is inefficient for a reason that eludes me. Suppose $E$ is a compact subset of a metric space $(X,d)$ and grab any $e\in E$. Now consider the *cover* $$\left\{ B_n (e) \right\}_{n\in \mathbf{N}}.$$ By compactness there is a subcover $$B_{n_1}(e), B_{n_2} (e), \cdots, B_{n_k}(e)$$ for some $k\in \mathbf{N}$. But if we let let $m=\max \left\{n_i: 1\leq i \leq k \right\}$, their union is exactly $$B_m  (e)$$ and we have that, by compactness: $$E\subseteq B_m (e).$$ Which precisely says that $E$ is bounded.$\blacksquare$ $$$$ As far as I can tell, the only qualm I can see one having with this proof is that $\left\{B_n (e) \right\}_{n\in \mathbf{N}}$ actually covered $E$. So if asked for a proof of this fact, what would I say? I suppose I could say for any $y\neq e$ we have that $y\in B_{\lfloor d(y,e) \rfloor +1} (e)$. Or, of course, if it’s *not true* what would a counter example be?

Comment: Of course $d(y,e) < \lfloor d(y,e)\rfloor + 1 =: n$, so what was your doubt about this part?

Comment: @AlexOrtiz yeah I don’t know. It’s honestly worse though as I could simply use the Archimedean Property to find a natural $k$ such that $$d(x,y) < k.$$ And I’m usually the guy that hesitates to use the floor function if he doesn’t need to.

Comment: You can take an even more "inefficient cover" if you don't want to use natural numbers and you want to avoid talking about the floor function. Take the collection $\{B_r(e):r>0\}$ of balls indexed by all the positive real numbers. Your same argument works for this cover.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sets $B_n(e)$ actually cover the whole space $X$, in particular the compact subset $E$.

Indeed, let $x\in X$: you can certainly find a natural number $n$ such that $d(x,e)<n$ and therefore $x\in B_n(e)$.

Yes, your proof is correct.

Comment: This follows from the so-called Archimedean property of $\Bbb R$: the numbers $\frac{1}{n}$ get arbitrarily close to $0$ and hence the set $\Bbb N$ is unbounded above, which implies that no $d(x,e)$ can be an upperbound for all of $\Bbb N$ etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma And the fact this is very easy should be a sign that establishing the converse might be quite hard… And in fact it's not true, because one needs a stricter notion of boundedness.

Comment: @egreg yeah maybe something like totally bounded and complete :P

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct. You could even take an arbitrary $e\in X$, and it's true that the balls $B_n(e)$ will cover $E$ (they even cover $X$). The point is that any two points $x,e$ in a metric space are *some* finite distance apart (namely $d(x,e)<\infty$) so in particular any point $x\in X$ will belong to $B_n(e)$ as long as $n > d(x,e)$.